# Solving a system of equations given a determinant

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I would like to solve the following equation system:

[image]

where: $\alpha$ is the unknown vector; $M$ and $K$ are constant matrices (8 x 8).

I don't really know how to solve this :/ (`LinearSolve` or some loop?)

Any ideas?

#### Update

Here is my code. Evaluation of the `Solve` expression runs indefinitely.

```
M = {{18.252581868563773`, 0.06705185574759391`, 
   0.5486060924803138`, -0.039621551123578215`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
   0.`}, {0.06705185574759391`, 0.09741329795773487`, 
   1.3410371149518783`, -0.0027430304624015693`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
   0.`}, {0.5486060924803138`, 0.039621551123578215`, 
   8.858972456348772`, 0.`, -0.039621551123578215`, 0.`, 0.`, 
   0.`}, {-0.039621551123578215`, -0.0027430304624015693`, 0.`, 
   0.027796042019002567`, -0.0027430304624015693`, 0.`, 0.`, 
   0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, -0.039621551123578215`, -0.0027430304624015693`, 
   0.007314747899737517`, 
   1.3410371149518783`, -0.0027430304624015693`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`,
    0.`, 0.039621551123578215`, 33.68554113363173`, 
   0.`, -0.039621551123578215`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
   0.`, -0.0027430304624015693`, 0.`, 
   0.2974057336718429`, -0.0027430304624015693`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,
    0.`, -0.039621551123578215`, -0.0027430304624015693`, 
   0.0036573739498687585`}}

K = {{2.432045103220617`*^7, 
   3.6480676548309256`*^6, -2.432045103220617`*^7, 
   3.6480676548309256`*^6, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {3.6480676548309256`*^6, 
   729613.5309661851`, -3.6480676548309256`*^6, 364806.7654830926`, 0,
    0, 0, 0}, {-2.432045103220617`*^7, -3.6480676548309256`*^6, 
   4.864090206441234`*^7, 0.`, 3.6480676548309256`*^6, 0, 0, 
   0}, {3.6480676548309256`*^6, 364806.7654830926`, 0.`, 
   1.4592270619323703`*^6, 364806.7654830926`, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
   3.6480676548309256`*^6, 364806.7654830926`, 
   1.4592270619323703`*^6, -3.6480676548309256`*^6, 
   364806.7654830926`, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, -3.6480676548309256`*^6, 
   4.864090206441234`*^7, 0.`, 3.6480676548309256`*^6}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
   364806.7654830926`, 0.`, 1.4592270619323703`*^6, 
   364806.7654830926`}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.6480676548309256`*^6, 
   364806.7654830926`, 729613.5309661851`}}

freqs = Table[Subscript[α, i], {i, MatrixRank[M]}];
EqOfFreq = -freqs^2 . M + K;
Solve[Det[EqOfFreq] == 0, freqs];
```

Comment: I assume $\alpha$ is the $a$ you're talking about. Then, how do you understand $a^2$?

Comment: That equation reminds me of my aeroelasticity home work :) Just find the polynomial with Determinant and then use Solve to find alpha. Why don't you post your matrices?

Comment: @MirkoAveta It's for calculating the vibration frequencies of a stucture accually:) Anyway, I posted my martices and tried your method, but the evaluation won't stop.

Comment: You have a complicated polynomial equation of degree 16 and with 8 variables. It's impossible that a closed form solution exists. `NSolve` returns an infinite number of solutions. And I suspect your code doesn't reflect what you want: 1) how do you understand `freqs^2.`, and 2) why did you put a dot after the exponent?

Comment: 1) Scalar product of freq and freq. Results a1*a1+a2*a2+a3*a3...so on, at least this is what I meant. 2) Just a typo, sorry

Comment: So: no. Run `freqs^2` and see what's the output. A scalar product (a dot product) is performed with the [`Dot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html): `freqs.freqs`. Then, `Det[EqOfFreq]` is a polynomial with 8 variables with degree 16 and... over 17 thousand terms.

Comment: Oh I see! I've alwasy used this form in paper, I thought Mathematica would implement it the same way. Thanks for the correction!:)

Comment: If you change `freqs^2` into some `x` (being the sum of squares of the alphas), as you multiply the whole matrix `M` with this scalar, you will then find with small accuracy (using `FindRoot`) that for the determinant to vanish `x = 19176.7`. Because you have one equation with 8 variables, you won't get anything more of a constraint, which is poor 'cause the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial span **55 orders of magnitude**.

Comment: Yes it is a funny annotation used in structural dynamics and also in aeroelasticity. Yet you have to keep in mind that freq^2 is read as power of two by mathematica, and this would mean two roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of `Det` is going to get you into ill conditioning as well as a needlessly nonlinear problem. Better to treat if as a generalized eigenvalues problem. It would also make sense to rescale the `K` matrix, say divide by 10^6 (Improves the numerics in terms of truncation error), but I will omit that below.

First find generalized eigenvalues, for which there are solutions (that is, nontrivial null vectors `v`) to `K.v-lambda*M.v==0`.

```
eigvals = Eigenvalues[{K, M}]

(* Out[61]= {3.38643*10^8, 2.07948*10^8, 5.2628*10^7, 1.54155*10^7, 
 3.86166*10^6, 1.07584*10^6, 397384., 19176.7} *)
```

For each `j` in `{1,...,8}`, in principle the determinant `Det[K-eigval[[j]]*M]` vanishes but due to the bad numerical conditioning this won't happen. All the same these are the values to use.

Obtaining those alphas is now a much simpler task. Here we do that for the first of the generalized eigenvalues.

```
Solve[-alf^2 == eigvals[[1]]]

(* Out[63]= {{alf -> 0. - 18402.3 I}, {alf -> 0. + 18402.3 I}} *)
```

Comment: Is there anything interesting you could add [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132212/12), perhaps comments on the (unfortunately) hacky solutions in the answers?  I described why I need this in the comments.

Comment: @Szabolcs Afraid that's too far out of my area to have anything to offer.