# Detecting kernel initialization

Tags: kernel, system, kernel-startup, initialization

[Certain operations do not work during kernel initialization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17164/12).  Code from `Kernel/init.m`, [the `Autoload` directory](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114957/12), or packages set to autoload may evaluate at initialization time.

Is there a way to detect if the kernel is currently initializing?

I need a piece of code that returns `True` if it is evaluated during initialization, e.g. if it is placed in `init.m`.

---

**Clarification:**  I am not looking to see if the currently loading file is `init.m`.  Any `init.m` may load at another time than initialization and even at init time, other files may get loaded too, or other code may get evaluated.

Comment: As far as `init.m` files go, you could use something like `StringMatchQ[$InputFileName, __ ~~ "init.m"]`. You could make it more precise by explicitly listing locations where `init.m` matters (i.e. system ones, to differentiate from packages).

Comment: Would `StringContainsQ[NotebookFileName[EvaluationNotebook[]], "init.m"]` work?

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be a serious suggestion or not... but until the long-standing bug reported in [(17164)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17164/142) is fixed, we can detect initialization using `initializingQ[] := CheckAll[Catch[Throw[False]], # /. Null -> True &]`.

Comment: @Leonid I wanted to use it for the following: My package uses `Import` and `RunProcess` during loading. These don't work during initialization. After I added proper documentation, there's a [setting in the doc center to make the package load on startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWV7o.png). If a user sets it, it will mess everything up.  So I want to make the package "initialization-resistant" by delaying "dangerous" operations until a package function is used for the first time. But *in general* it is more user-friendly to let the package report misconfiguration as soon as it ...

Comment: @Leonid ... is loaded.   So I only want to delay these operations if the package is set to load at startup, but not otherwise.  I know that this sounds like a whole lot of complication for little gain, but I thought it doesn't hurt to ask.  Now I found a way to detect initialization, but I am not really comfortable using such stuff. So I might just not implement this at all.  Still investigating `initializing[]` from WReach.

Comment: @WReach Why not post an answer?

Comment: @Szabolcs I see. Thanks for explaining. It sounds sensible.

Comment: closely related: [Handling Kernel start. What is a full initialization stack ...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110243/5478)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apparently, `Throw` is deactivated during kernel initialization.  The following function can determine if `Throw` is inoperative:

```
throwInoperativeQ[] := CheckAll[Catch[Throw[False]], # /. Null -> True &]
```

The undocumented function [CheckAll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48493/142) is used here because `Check` also appears to be unreliable when `Throw` is inoperative.

If we make the assumption that `Throw` is non-functional if and only if the kernel is still initializing, then we can define:

```
kernelInitializingQ = throwInoperativeQ;
```

The deactivation of `Throw` during initialization seems to be intentional but it [might be changed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17164/stringmatchq-and-alternatives-throws-message-in-init-m#comment356771_17562) in some future release.  This behaviour goes back to at least V7 and probably even earlier.  It was reported to WRI and given the classification number *[TS 86]*.  It is the root cause of the defect described in [(17164)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17164/142).

I feel that this work-around is on very shaky ground given that it uses an undocumented function, undocumented behaviour, and a lot of guesswork.  I offer it up "for science".

**Work-around for complex initializations**

There are many cases where code that does more than install definitions will fail at start-up.  This may very well be due to the deactivation of `Throw` and similar non-local control flow constructs.  If this behaviour is changed is some future release, it may reduce or eliminate the need to detect whether initialization is in progress.  In the meantime, using an immediately scheduled task might dodge the problem (depending upon the exact nature of the initialization):

```
RunScheduledTask[
  (* perform some complex initialization *)
; RemoveScheduledTask @ $ScheduledTask
, {0}
]
```

Comment: So scheduled tasks are delayed until initialization has finished?  Let me try this.

Comment: Yes.  I have used this work-around successfully before.  However, take note that the asynchronous nature of those tasks might permit some processing to sneak in before the task fires, introducing the possibility of a race condition.  Like so much in WL, a work-around that is just fine for an end user might not be suitable for use in a library.  Library writers have a tough time in WL :(

Comment: @WReach Everybody has a tough time in WL ...

Comment: According to Ilian, 1 sec should be enough :) [Possible Bug of loading Package](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84589/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Errrm, not really... all that post claims is that an *example* (exempli gratia) time of 1 second is something I've used as a workaround. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @ilian Sorry for confusion, the point was to link that topic. ":)" meant to add uncertainty to 1sec :)

Comment: @ilian I saw your comment only now. I couldn't get this to work reliably in some cases with 0 seconds, so I also ended up using 1 second (just for personal packages, not anything released).

Answer (score 14):

After some spelunking, I found a file which contains a lot of initialization code, including reading the kernel `init.m` file, loading `Autoload` packages, loading anything set with the `-initfile` option, starting the paclet manager (which may autoload packages), and many other things.  It is

```
SystemFiles/Kernel/SystemResources/$SystemID/sysinit.m
```

Towards the end this file sets

```
System`Private`$InitsLoaded = True;
```

Thus checking

```
TrueQ[System`Private`$InitsLoaded]
```

seems like a practical way to check that initialization has already finished.  This symbol is present in at least 9.0–11.0.  There are no other references to this symbol in any plaintext `.m` files in the installation directory (but I don't know about `.mx` files).

---

The usual caveats about undocumented stuff apply more than ever.