# Package loading in init.m

Tags: packages, kernel, kernel-startup

I'm loading a package at startup in "~/Library/Mathematica/Kernel.init", which looks like this:

```
(** User Mathematica initialization file **)
Print["Loading Custom Packages"];
Get["~/my_package.wl"];
```

Is this not the right place to put this? Because unfortunately, this causes the kernel to hang on startup:

[image]

Loading the package after startup works:

```
(** User Mathematica initialization file **)
load[]:=Get["~/my_package.wl"];
```

[image]

Here are the first two lines of the package:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, InitializationCellWarning] = False;
BeginPackage["CoreUtils`", {"GeneralUtilities`", "DatabaseLink`"}];
```

Comment: Can you show what is in that package?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Unfortunately not, it's not mine, it's for work. But I can show the first two lines, see above.

Comment: What is of interest is whether it makes use of various functions that require signalling, such as `Throw`, `Break`, and the like. These do not work during loading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all packages can be loaded on startup.  There are some operations that simply do not work during startup, the most prominent one being `Throw`/`Catch`.

For this reason, it is generally not a good idea to load packages on startup.

See my questions about this here:

- [Detecting kernel initialization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132212/12)

These came up while I was trying to make my own packages "init-resistant".

#### What can *you* do to avoid the problem?

What can you do then?

You can use @WReach's suggestion from the post I linked.  Load the package in a scheduled task:

```
RunScheduledTask[
  (* perform some complex initialization *)
; RemoveScheduledTask @ $ScheduledTask
, {0}
]
```

This did not work for me unless I set a non-zero value for the delay.  It did work when I set it to 1 second.

But I am not comfortable with this solution.  What if the kernel startup is triggered by evaluating a cell which has code that relies on the package you are loading?

**Aside:** I have also seen it many times that starting up the kernel by evaluating certain cells will trigger crashes or other misbehaviour sometimes.  This was affecting some of my notebooks when I was using version 8 on a not very fast computer.  Since then I did not encounter this frequently, though 11.1 tends to randomly start up very slowly for me when kernel start is triggered by cell initialization.  I have no proof, but all these problems *could* be explained by such scheduled tasks ... if such things are used internally within Mathematica.  I am just guessing that this might be related to scheduled tasks, and I am probably wrong. Do not take it too seriously.

Another thing you can do is use [`DeclarePackage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeclarePackage.html) and list every symbol in that package.  Then the package will load only when you actually use something from it.

#### What can the package author do to avoid the problem?

The best solution would be to ask the person who wrote the package to make it init-friendly.  I wrote about how to do this here:

- http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/982404

For most packages this is easy.  For others, not so much.